# How to authorize Rest API in Oracle Cloud?

Tags: oracle, oauth-2.0, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating a web application where users have the option to connect to Oracle Cloud. After authenticating to Oracle Cloud, our application will call Oracle Cloud APIs.

As I know, we can create an OAuth 2.0 application, but it will be only available within same tenant where it is created. Is there a way that users can connect to our application using their Oracle Cloud account?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/oauth/oauth-settings.htm

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly you can use the Oracle IDCS service from OCI.

IDCS document : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/oauth/oauth-settings.htm

SSO with multi-tenancy: https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/how-to-set-up-single-sign-on-between-multiple-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-tenancies